# attaching behavior to elements created by knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Take, for example, the situation using knockoutjs:

```
<div id="container" data-bind="foreach:containers">
    <li class="complex-element">...</li>
</div>
```

Now I want to attach some complex behavior to `complex-element`. How do I do that? I can't just attach events directly to complex-element, as they're created and removed dynamically at runtime to match the view model. So, as I see it:

I can riddle my html with `data-bind="click:..."`s and `data-bind="mouseenter:..."`s but I would rather avoid this if I could. Maybe I'm too rooted in my old MVC ways, but adding `open()`, `select()`, or `dragStart()` functions and `isOpen`, `isSelected` or `isDragging` observable flags to my view model just makes a mess and my intuition tells me that as the app gets bigger that view model is going to become unmanageable. I'd rather keep my data and my presentation separate if possible.

Or I can use jquery delegation to attach events to something that stays fixed. Something like:

```
$("#container").on('click', '.complex-element button.open', function(e) {
    var elem = $(e.target).parents('.complex-element');
    ...
});
```

But this wouldn't work as the app gets more complex because what happens if the container is itself wrapped in an element only shown on login (`<div id="wrapper" data-bind="if:isLoggedIn">...</div>`). I might as well just bind all events to the body and that's a recipe for disaster.

I found a very cool article on knockmeout.net (http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) that advocates using custom knockout bindings to drive complex behavior, and this seems to be an awesome solution for widget-like behaviors like autocompletes or date-pickers, but what about just simple old fashioned controllers... would this work?

I guess, after all that, my question is pretty simple: Has anyone used Knockoutjs on a really large web application? And how did you go about it?

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you implemented your framework.  We are working on a single page app which implements a sort of MVVMC concept that started after reading this blog series: http://blog.monnet-usa.com/ This keeps all of our viewModels separate and mostly unaware of each other.  they subscribe to each other inside the controllers.  It turns into a very manageable source code layout.  Especially when used with an external template engine ( to keep our primary markup clean until a certain model is required to be loaded. ). Though I am startng to see modelView bloat due to behaviors.

Comment: @BrandonWittwer: I'll take a look at that blog. I hadn't found that! Thanks. I'm still pondering the problem. I flip almost daily from being a huge MVVM fan to wanting to throw it all out and start over in a more structured module pattern like Nicholas Zakas talks about (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw). Neither approach is really working for me though. MVVM has the "where does behavior logic go" problem, a strictly module pattern falls apart when your dealing with data more complicated, and more inter-related, than weather and stocks. If I figure it out I'll let you know...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a different jquery bind:

```
$(document).on('click', '#container>.complex-element button.open', function(e) {
    var elem = $(e.target).parents('.complex-element');
    ...
});
```

This would work if `#container` does not exist.

There is some work going on in the community to make the knockout bindings unobtrusive and easy to write.  For now, knockout offers you `dataFor()` which can be seen here: [Using unobtrusive event handlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) or you can use a little library like this: [Introducing the Knockout.Unobtrusive Plugin](http://userinexperience.com/?p=689)

Comment: I'm also in the process of re-writing knockout.unobtrusive to use the KO v2 Binding Providers model. Here's a WIP branch: https://github.com/bsatrom/Knockout.Unobtrusive/tree/ko-v2

Answer (score 2):

If you need to execute some arbitrary js on some rendered elements from the foreach you could use the afterAdd callback

```
<div id="container" data-bind="foreach: { data: containers, 
               afterAdd: somefunction }">
    <li class="complex-element">...</li>
</div>
```

I have used KO on a really large web app and the way I went about managing complexity was

1. Split out viewmodels into separate using namespaces within a single master namespace.
2. Write custom bindings for complex reusable behavior.
3. Created entity model classes that encapsulated most of the important business logic, akin to backbone models.
4. Ensured that the viewModels were entirely view specific and view related (helped by point 3)
5. Kept all jquery selectors to a bare minimum, I feel dirty writing any global delegates but sometimes they are needed.

Hope this helps.